# How to use an index on a variable

Tags: c#

I have a list which I currently add items to in the following way:

```
public GameObject object1 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object2 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object3 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object4 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object5 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object6 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object7 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object8 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object9 = new GameObject("Example Data");
public GameObject object10 = new GameObject("Example Data");
List<GameObject> Objects = new List<GameObject>();

Objects.Add(object1);
Objects.Add(object2);
Objects.Add(object3);
Objects.Add(object4);
Objects.Add(object5);
Objects.Add(object6);
Objects.Add(object7);
Objects.Add(object8);
Objects.Add(object9);
Objects.Add(object10);
```

How would I do this in C# using a foreach? I tried something like the following example but I couldn't get it to work:

```
foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
    Objects.Add("object" + [number]);
}
```

Comment: Where you getting that objects?

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read a private field using a dynamically-generated name, you'll need to write a special function to read it via Reflection. Here is how I would write such a function:

```
public static object GetFieldValue(this object input, string name)
{
    return input
        .GetType()
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .ToList()
        .Where(f => f.Name == name)
        .Single()
        .GetValue(input);
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string fieldName = "object" + i.ToString();
    var o = this.GetFieldValue(fieldName);
    objects.Add(o);
}
```

That being said, this is not a great idea. In fact, this is a ***really*** weird thing to do. The normal way you'd deal with this is to omit the `objectX` variables completely; just store each instance in the list.

```
List<GameObject> Objects = new List<GameObject>();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Objects.Add(new GameObject("Example data"));
}
```

If you need to get one of the instances back out of the list, just reference it by index (although you may have to subtract 1 since it is 0-based):

```
var object1 = Objects[0];
```

Another way to deal with it, especially if each of those instances is unique in some way, it to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, GameObject> objects = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
objects["Player"] = new GameObject("I am a player");
objects["Enemy"] = new GameObject("I am an enemy");
objects["NPC"] = new GameObject("I am a hapless bystander");
```

Then you can access each of the individual objects by name, or you can iterate over all of them if you need to, e.g. if you need to dipose one object you can use

```
objects["Player"].Dispose();
objects.Remove("Player");
```

and if you need to dispose of everything at once (e.g. the game is over):

```
foreach (var o in objects) o.Dispose();
objects.Clear();
```

As a rule, if you find yourself putting numbers in variable names, you have probably made a mistake in your design. It is almost always better to put them into an array, list, or other data structure meant to contain multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks very much for your extremely detailed answer!

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to convert a string to a variable name, but depending what you are trying to do you could get rid of the `object1` variables completely via:

```
// Personally I'd use a simple for loop instead of this 
foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
    Objects.Add(new GameObject("Example Data"));
}
```

Edit: Using a range of 1..10 is going to confuse you somewhere down the road. In C# everything is 0 based. Just suck it up and don't try to pretend it isn't...

Comment: If you like `for` loop, why you suggesting `Enumerable.Range`?

Comment: @tym32167 because that is what OP had in their original code.

Comment: @tym32167 No, I'm saying I would do it in a simpler way. How OP does the loop is not relevant to the question so leaving it as is makes it easier for the OP to see how my snippet fits into their question. I think it is a useful hint that "this area could be improved" but without rewriting all of the OPs stuff for them - I don't get paid for that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a for loop.  Loop through `i` times and create a new object and add it to your list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    GameObject ob = new GameObject("Example Data " + i);
    Objects.Add(ob);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with reflection.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public GameObject object1 = new GameObject("g1");
    public GameObject object2 = new GameObject("g2");
    public GameObject object3 = new GameObject("g3");

    public void AddObject()
    {
        List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            var o = this.GetType().GetField($"object{i}").GetValue(this) as GameObject;    
            list.Add(o);
        }           
    }
}
```